# How do I repeat an animation multiple times simultaneously with respect to performance?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, cabasicanimation, sktexture

I am aiming to have all these waves animate identically, for performance reasons. This will help by reducing the cost of calculating wave paths, and to reduce the draw count.

I have a scene in SpriteKit setup like so:

[image: Scene]
→ There is a link to an animating version [here](https://streamable.com/y1z5l).

The scene is mainly composed of 2 things:

- Stones (the light and dark grey hexagons)
- Waves (there are 2 per stone - a lighter and a darker blue animating path)

The waves are create like so:

```
// Wave outline shape node
shapeNode               = SKShapeNode(path: self.oldPath)
shapeNode.strokeColor   = wave.color
shapeNode.lineWidth     = 5
shapeNode.zPosition     = waveIndex == 0 ? Layer.farWave : Layer.nearWave
shapeNode.lineJoin      = .round
shapeNode.position      = stoneCell.node.position.offset(by: stoneCell.offsetVector)
view.scene?.addChild(shapeNode)

// Layer which creates the animation
shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.isHidden = true
view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

animate()
```

And the `animate()` function:

```
/// Animates the wave's path. This method calls itself forever.
private func animate() {
    let newPath = WavePath(wave: wave, direction: currentDirection).createPath()

    let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    anim.duration   = 2  // Duration of the wave movements in a direction (in or out)
    anim.fromValue  = oldPath
    anim.toValue    = newPath
    anim.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)

    shapeLayer.path = newPath
    shapeLayer.add(anim, forKey: nil)

    shapeNode.run(SKAction.customAction(withDuration: anim.duration, actionBlock: { (node, timeDuration) in
        (node as? SKShapeNode)?.path = self.shapeLayer.presentation()?.path
    }), completion: {
        self.oldPath = newPath
        self.currentDirection.toggle()
        self.animate()
    })
}
```

The problems arise because there are 10 stones on the scene, which increases the performance cost. Is there a way to make this wave animation duplicated under all these stones?

Possible options I can think of:

- Convert the paths into a texture, which could be shared between multiple stones? However I think this would be slow to convert to a texture twice (for each wave) per frame, and then copy it over...
- Rendering a full animation pass of the wave going in and then out, and then putting that on a loop for every node. But how?

What other solutions may be better?

I do **not** want to create an atlas and animate it. I cannot do this because these stones and waves change in size, depending on the screen size and level and I want them pixel-perfect. I do not mind however (as mentioned in bullet point two) of storing textures of an animation loop and then repeating that.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the current approach has a performance impact?

Comment: @Paulw11 Xcode shows that the performance is quite noticeable. I compared drawing one stone to drawing all ten: Memory goes from 50MB to 55MB, but most importantly, the CPU jumps from ~40% to ~70% which is very significant.

Comment: Is there any reason you can’t make your waves all 1 huge skshapennode?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I don't understand what you mean by this... Do you mean combining all 10 waves into 1 somehow?

Comment: @George_E yes, take all your paths, and place it into 1 SKShapeNode

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I am creating the waves by using the SKShapeNode's `init`. So are you suggesting place these SKShapeNodes into one SKShapeNode (or is there some `init` which takes an array of paths)? How will this increase performance?

Comment: you take all of the paths that you would normally use to create the individual shapes and merge them all together into 1 path.  You then turn that 1 path into 1 SKShapeNode, which will increase performance because the system is now working on 1 SKShapeNode instead of 10